# What is this lapel pin logo?

Tags: europe, cold-war, hungary, yugoslavia, czechoslovakia

I got this lapel pin in the mid-1980s from a retired communist partisan in Hungary. He had more pins, mostly of communist/socialist organisations, trade fairs, and combines.[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combine_(enterprise))]

cold-war era Eastern bloc, probably Hungary, Czechoslovakia, or Yugoslavia, ~1960 … 1980

[image: A triangular lapel pin, depicting a cogwheel with a 'K' in its middle and three arrows pointing from the wheel to the triangle's corners.]

Does anyone recognize the logo? Any help is appreciated!